# Pythonic Way to Define Status Constants

Tags: python, optimization, constants, status

I wrote a function which could output three things:

```
def getStatus():
    if   condition1:
        return "NormalStatus"
    elif condition2:
        return "ServerCompromised"
    elif condition3:
        return "UnknownStatus"
```

If I were writing C++ code, I would use `#define` to make some status constants which were just ints, so that the function isn't returning strings each time. Is there a Pythonic equivalent to avoid using string like this?

I intend to call this function several million times, so doing a string comparison on the output might be much slower than comparing a constant int.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.4 or later, try the [`enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). Otherwise, just define constants using all-uppercase letters and underscores between words.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own mapping in a dictionary like `{1: "NormalStatus", 2: "ServerCompromised"}` and so on. Then you can return Integers and only have to lookup these integers in the dict (if necessary).

An alternative was already mentioned in a comment: You can also use the [enum module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for this. Maybe the most similar way to `#define` is declaring (global) variables like this:

```
NORMAL_STATUS = 1
SERVER_COMPROMISED = 2
...
```

But as mentioned in the module documentation of the enum module

> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique, constant values.

this could also be seen as the most similar way of getting C++'s `#define` into Python.

Comment: If the keys are numbers, wouldn't a list be easier?

Comment: It depends on the usecase. A dict is more flexibel and fast in lookup and there you can have a clear visible mapping between numbers and text.

Comment: I think `enum` is the closest to what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [enum](https://kite.com/python/docs/enum) module for that. If you need to compare values to integers it's good to subclass from [enum.IntEnum](https://kite.com/python/docs/enum.IntEnum)

Comment: It's basically what I've said, but you focused on using enum module with a little bit more information (subclassing). Enough for me to upvote.